# iPhone unit test overlapping drawing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, unit-testing, nsstring

I am subclassing a UITableViewCell and drawing its content view manually by calling `drawInRect:` on NSString objects. Here is a simplified sample of my code:

```
- (void)drawContentView:(CGRect)rect {
    CGSize nameSize = [self textSizeForName:self.name];
    [self.name drawInRect:CGRectMake(kPadding, kPadding,
                                     nameSize.width, nameSize.height)];

    CGSize blurbSize = [self textSizeForBlurb:self.blurb];
    [self.blurb drawInRect:CGRectMake(kWindowWidth - blurbSize.width - kPadding, 
                                      kPadding, blurbSize.width, blurbSize.height)];
}
```

Is there a way to write a unit test case to make sure that none of it is overlapping and that my logic is right in avoiding collisions between the various strings I am drawing?